# Map primary key composed of two foreign keys? hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have 3 classes Player(PK Id_player), Match(PK Id_match) and Inscription(PK should be Id_player and Id_match). A Player has ONE and ONLY ONE inscription(1 Player-> 1 Inscription), and a Match can be in many inscriptions(1 Match -> Many inscriptcions). So the table Inscriptions have 2 foreig keys Id_player and Id_match, the problem is that I don't how to tell hibernate that both foreing keys must be a composed primarey key for Inscriptions Table. This is my code::

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "Players")

public class Player{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
private Long Id_player;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "payer_id")
Inscription Inscription;}

@Entity
@Table(name="Matches")
public class Match{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long Id_match;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_match")
    List<Inscription> inscriptions= new ArrayList<>();
```

What should I write on Inscription class to make both Fk's a composed PK.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

Player

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity

@Table(name = "Players")

public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id_player;

    @OneToOne
    private Match match;

}
```

Match

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Matches")
public class Match{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long Id_match;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Inscription",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MATCH_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PLAYER_ID"))
    private List<Player> playersList;


    public long getId_match() {
        return Id_match;
    }

    public void setId_match(long id_match) {
        Id_match = id_match;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayersList() {
        return playersList;
    }

    public void setPlayersList(List<Player> playersList) {
        this.playersList = playersList;
    }


}
```